# Meteor build triggering npm script

Tags: meteor, build, npm-scripts

Is there a native way (no additional npm/meteor packages) to trigger a NPM script during/before/after `meteor build` that is located in my `package.json`?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Meteor Build plugins API http://docs.meteor.com/api/packagejs.html#build-plugin-api

> Build Plugins API
>
> Meteor packages can provide build plugins - programs that integrate
>   with the build tool Isobuild used to compile and bundle your
>   application.
>
> Starting with Meteor 1.2, the API used to plug into the build process
>   is called “Build Plugins”. There are 3 phases when a package’s plugin
>   can run: linting, compilation and minification. Here is an overview of
>   operations Isobuild performs on the application and packages source:

Comment: Though this way _is_ *native*, it will require building additional meteor package :)